# How to limit number of order per customer for certain product? - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I have a requirement in my website where the customer can buy a certain product only once. If they try to buy that again it should throw an error saying cannot purchase this again.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only one or few products like that - the best way in my opinion is to add attribute to customer and change it after product is purchased.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question...

**Solution:-**

**1-** You've to create product attribute as Yes/No & by default, it'll be No.you've to select as Yes for the product which you want to avail purchase only once.

**2-** **If a customer is logged in**, then during Add to Cart if a product can purchase only once for a customer then before adding to cart(use observer here) you've to check if a customer already purchases this item if yes then you've to avoid
Add to Cart else customer can add this to cart.

**3-** **If a customer is not logged in**, in this case, it depends on you.

**There may be 2 cases:-**

**a-** Simply customer can be added to cart any item & after login, if a customer has added the restricted item(only once purchase) then you've to remove the restricted item from the cart if already purchased else vice versa.

**b-** **OR** you don't allow to Add To Cart(by an observer) restricted item if a customer is not logged in.

Hope it'll resolve your problem.